# How do I find Source FQDN, Source IP, Port, Protocol, Service on Azure App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How do I find the following for my azure web app. I am on a premium service. and I am unsure of where to look.

Source FQDN
Source IP
Port
Protocol
Service
Is the flow bi-directional?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is asking, but I'll provide some info based on some assumptions of what you're asking for:

- **FQDN**: When you created your app service, you gave it a name. If you named it "gcase" then your FQDN would be `gcase.azurewebsites.net`.
- **IP**: It depends on what you mean by this. If you're trying to address your App Service, then go into the *Custom Domains* tab of the blade and you will see an IP address for mapping custom DNS to. Note that this is only available for certain tiers of App Service Plans. However, if you need to know what IPs this can potentially connect to other services from, then go into the *Properties* tab of the blade and you will see a field labelled "Outbound IP Addresses".
- **Port** and **Protocol** and **Bi-Directional Flow**: This totally depends on the software you install on there. We cannot tell you this.

If you can clear up your question, we can help you more. Otherwise, this is the best answer I can give you to your question as it is currently written.